# How to overload () operator for a class using boost::dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, byte, bit, bitset

I've created a class that simulates 2d set of data from a bitset. Here's what I've created so far:

```
class Data
{
    private: 
        int width_; 
        int height_; 
        boost::dynamic_bitset<> * bitset_; dynamicznie

    public:
        Data() : width_(0), height_(0) {} 
        Data(int width,  int height) : width_(width), height_(height) 
        {
            bitset_ = new boost::dynamic_bitset<>(width * height); 
        }

    boost::dynamic_bitset<>::reference & operator()(const int x, const int y)
    {
        return bitset_[x * height_ + y];
    }

};
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, it indicates an error:

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<>::reference & operator()(const int x, const int y)
    {
        return bitset_[x * height_ + y];
    }
```

I want to be able to manipulate bitset in instance of this class like that:

```
Data data = new Data(10, 10);
bool i = 1
data(0, 1) = i;
```

Comment: What is the error that it indicates?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, dynamic_bitset provides an operator[] on its own. You have declared it as a pointer, so square brackets are treated as that pointer's index access; it treats your pointer as a pointer to array and returns an (unexisting and unallocated) element of that array, which is a (dangling) reference to a dynamic_bitset, not a reference to a single bit.

Is there any real reason to have that member as a pointer? You don't even handle it in copy/assignment/destruction, thus violating the Rule of five. Simply make it an object member, not a pointer to something allocated on the heap:

```
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bitset;
public:
    Data(int w, int h): width_(w), height_(h), bitset(w * h) {}
```

P.S. `std::size_t` makes more sense as a dimension size, if you don't really use negative sizes.

Answer (score 1):

`bitset_` is a pointer, you should dereference it before using

```
    (*bitset_)[x * height_ + y];
```

and remember that `operator[]` for `dynamic_bitset` return temporary object,

> reference operator[](size_type pos);
>
> bool operator[](size_type pos) const;

you cannot assign it to L-value reference - `dynamic_bitset<>::reference&`. So you should define your operator () as follows

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<>::reference  operator()(const int x, const int y)
{
    return (*bitset_)[x * height_ + y];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't post another question, so I'll post it here. I wanna understand the algorithm for generating fractals from IFS functions. This algorithm code is here: 
http://www.algorytm.org/fraktale/system-funkcji-iterowanych-ifs/ifs-c.html 
But I can't understand whast is the purpose of minX, minY, maxX, maxY, ratioX, ratioY variables. I just can't. I've been thinking a lot and can't figure out.

What is interesting these valubes have to be set to specific values. Otherwise the algorith doesn't work correctly (I've tested that).